# How to combine foreach loop with sed on text files?

Tags: unix, text, sed, foreach

So I have a command that outputs information from a non-text file into a text file and I want to do a for each loop on like 10 of these files.  Something like,

```
print_h3_header 2034.h3 > 2034_header.txt
```

Then I want to extract specific lines from the text file.  Something like,

```
sed '7929p;7936p;7937q;d' 2034_header.txt > 2034_extracted.txt
```

Is there a way I can do all of this in 1 giant step?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, all you need is

```
print_h3_header 2034.h3 | sed '7929p;7936p;7937q;d' > 2034_extracted.txt
```

Comment: but I have 10 other files I want to do this with.  How do I do it in the context of a foreach loop?

Comment: For that, see karakfa's answer.

Answer (score 1):

you're doing the same for all files with `.h3` extension

```
for f in *.h3; 
do 
  print_h3_header "$f" | sed '...' > ${f%.*}_extracted.txt; 
done
```

Comment: What does f stand for?

Comment: it the loop iterator, corresponding to the file names from the glob expansion of `*.hs`.